# How to hide middle 4 number of mobile number?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We are using Open CTI in our system. I have developed a lightning component to display some lead's information in the side bar. In the lightning component I use  to complete the click to dial funtion. And now we need hide the middle  4 numbers of mobile, but I found if I replace the mobile to  the click to dial will no longer work. Is there any way to complete this requirement? Thanks.

from[image] to [image]

```
<td>
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.OBcall.Prospect__r.MobilePhone))}">
     <div class="slds-truncate">
         <lightning:clickToDial value="{!'+' + v.OBcall.Prospect__r.MobilePhone}"/>
     </div>
</aura:if>
</td>
```

Comment: You won't be able to mask the values on the component. However, an approach could be to use say custom button which displays a masked value and that `onclick` of the button, you invoke the Open CTI APIs directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use traditional anchor tag inside which you can add the masked phone number as pure text. To give it look and feel like that of `lightning:clickToDial`, use a boolean and add custom styles based on its value:

**Component markup :**

```
<!-- Contains the actual phone number-->
    <aura:attribute name="phoneNumber" type="String" default="+12345678910"/>

    <!-- Contains the formatted phone number-->
    <aura:attribute name="formattedPhoneNumber" type="String" default="+123****8910"/>

    <!-- Boolean to apply custom styling-->
    <aura:attribute name="enableClickToDial" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.enableClickToDial}">
    <a href="{!'tel:' + v.phoneNumber}">
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:call" size="xx-small" class="blueEnabled"/>
        {!v.formattedPhoneNumber}
    </a>
    <aura:set attribute="else">
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:end_call" size="xx-small"/>
        {!v.formattedPhoneNumber}
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

**Style:**

```
.THIS .blueEnabled .slds-icon-text-default{
    fill: rgb(0, 109, 204) !important;
}
```

> When boolean is true:

[image]

> When boolean is false:

[image]